# Where should one put a bin directory in Linux?

Tags: linux

If i have the source folder of a program containing a /bin directory, what is the "classic" directory to put it in Linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) to find out where to store different files

In your project you can store files as you want. [For example](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/):

- bin: The output executables go here, both for the app and for any
  tests and spikes.
- build: This folder contains all object files, and
  is removed on a clean.
- doc: Any notes, like my assembly notes and
  configuration files, are here. I decided to create the development
  and production config files in here instead of in a separate config
  folder as they “document” the configuration.
- include: All project
  header files. All necessary third-party header files that do not
  exist under /usr/local/include are also placed here.
- lib: Any libs
  that get compiled by the project, third party or any needed in
  development. Prior to deployment, third party libraries get moved to
  /usr/local/lib where they belong, leaving the project clean enough to
  compile on our Linux deployment servers. I really use this to test
  different library versions than the standard.
- spike: I often write
  smaller classes or files to test technologies or ideas, and keep them
  around for future reference. They go here, where they do not dilute
  the real application’s files, but can still be found later.
- src: The
  application and only the application’s source files. test: All test
  code files. You do write tests, no?

There are more standard ways (GNU C++ standard project?). It also depends of tools you are using.

Comment: if i use /bin directory to place only the executable of the program i downloaded (mongoDB in my case), can i start mongo from terminal directly ? (without changing $PATH)

Comment: You can provide full path or relative path to executable mongo from terminal.

Comment: if  i just execute "./mongo" not being in mongoDB/bin directory it doesn't work, i have to add it to the $PATH variable

Comment: Yes, but instead of typing `./mongo`, you can type relative path to mongo, for example `./../../bin/mongo`, or you can use absolute path `/usr/bin/mongo`. I don't know right path, but it is only an idea. Why don't you want modify $PATH?

Comment: Dot in the start of path means current directory, slash means absolute path. `./mongo` means execute mongo from current directory. `/usr/bin/mongo` means execute mongo from given path. `./../../bin/mongo` means up to 2 folders, than go to bin folder and than execute mongo.

Comment: Okay, so how do i do if i want to execute mongo from any directory after having put the path to the executable in $PATH variable ? (i tried "./mongo" and "mongo" no result)

Comment: After adding path to `bin` directory where mongo lays, you should call it like `mongo`, without dot and slash. Dot and slash means execute it from current directory. In PATH you should place path to `bin` directory, not to executable itself!!!

Comment: ok, i forgot to add /bin to  my path in $PATH, it works, thanks !!!